# C# is a 'field' but used like a 'type' list

Tags: c#, list

Hello this is my first time posting, so correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

I am a beginner, I am trying to make a sort of text adventure game only using a winform and buttons as the control. The problem is when I try to make an inventory list. It is giving me an syntax error saying

> "Inventory is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

This is the code in question:

```
public partial class MainGameWindow : Form
{ 
    //sets the room ID to the first room as default
    string roomID = "FirstRoom";
    //makes a list for the inventory
    List<string> Inventory = new List<string>();
    Inventory.Add("A piece of string...Useless!");
}
```

Comment: Is the error on one of those lines (they seem ok by themselves)? You may need to include more code

Comment: If I copy your code and try to compile it, it works fine.

Comment: Actually double-click on the error in the Error List and it should take you to the offending line.

Comment: Your code needs to be in a method, like the constructor for the form.

Comment: @Sascha Which compiler did you try this in?

Comment: You are writing code in the declaration section of the class, maybe that is why you are getting the error. You will have to move `Inventory.Add("A piece of string...Useless!");` to a method like `Form_Load` etc.

Comment: @Asad: I've copied only the code lines. Haven't seen he has placed the code directly to the class..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you cannot have "action" in the body of the class, you have to put it in a method/function or constructor like

```
public partial class MainGameWindow : Form
{ 
    //sets the room ID to the first room as default
    string roomID = "FirstRoom";
    //makes a list for the inventory

    //collection initializer way (thanks to Max bellow!)
    List<string> Inventory = new List<string>()
    {
        "A piece of string...Useless!",
    };

    //constructor way
    public MainGameWindow()
    {
        Inventory.Add("A piece of string...Useless!");
    }

    //method way
    public void MethodAddUselessString()
    {
        Inventory.Add("A piece of string...Useless!");
    }

    //function way
    public bool FunctionAddUselessString()
    {
        Inventory.Add("A piece of string...Useless!");

        return true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: +1. I had just assumed this was in a method after a quick glance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a collection initializer syntax for `Inventory`:

```
public partial class MainGameWindow : Form
{
    List<string> Inventory = new List<string>()
    {
        "A piece of string...Useless!",
    };
}
```

Comment: +1, didn't know that, we learn thing everyday!

Answer (score 1):

Your are calling `Inventory.Add` in the class. You need to put it inside method.